# Adding characters/letters to value based on condition in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame of ID numbers, and I wish to add a suffix based on a specific condition.

**ID**

```
+----------+
|    ID    |
+----------+
| 130239   |
| 130241   |
| 130244   |
| 130250_2 |
| 130313_2 |
| 130248_2 |
| 130308_3 |
+----------+
```

Essentially if there is no `_` in the ID number, I want to add the suffix `_1`, to denote sample 1. If `_` is present, then I do not wish there to be any action taken.

I've tried writing an if-else statement combined with a grepl argument, within a loop so that I can apply the if-else statement to each ID individually:

```
for (value in ID){
  if(grepl('_', value)){
    paste0(value, collapse=NULL)
  }else {
    paste(value, sep = "_1", collapse=NULL)
  }
}
```

I get the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In if (grepl("_", value)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Basically I want my final output dataframe to look like this:

```
+----------+
|    ID    |
+----------+
| 130239_1 |
| 130241_1 |
| 130244_1 |
| 130250_2 |
| 130313_2 |
| 130248_2 |
| 130308_3 |
+----------+
```

I suspect I can't use `grepl` like I have here. I've tried to read similar solutions on using dplyer `mutate`, but I am still stick. Looking for an working AND efficient solution so I can learn "ideal coding principles". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a logical index based on the occurence of `_`.  Negate (`!`), subset the 'ID' column and `paste` the suffix `_1` to it and assign the values back to the column

```
i1 <- !grepl("_", df1$ID)
df1$ID[i1] <- paste0(df1$ID[i1], "_1")
df1
#        ID
#1 130239_1
#2 130241_1
#3 130244_1
#4 130250_2
#5 130313_2
#6 130248_2
#7 130308_3
```

With `grepl`, we modify only a part of the column.  Would be useful particularly when dealing with big datasets

---

The warning is OP's code is based on the use of `if/else` which is not vectorized.  For that we can use `ifelse`

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("130239", "130241", "130244", "130250_2", 
 "130313_2", "130248_2", "130308_3")), class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thanks, akrun for a nice solution. I understand the first line: you are applying a logical operator to all IDs that don't contain `_`. Am i right in saying that the second line adds `_1` for every TRUE value in `i1`? I am also confused about the second line: does the `0` after `paste` need to be there if you are adding suffix `_1`? It looks like it still works with `paste` alone, but I want to make sure I'm not missing something conceptually. Thank you.

Comment: @EdmondKwan  Regarding your first point, yes, with`grepl` it is checking for pattern `_`, and then do the negate (`!`) TRUE-> FALSE and viiceversa.  Use that index to filter the 'ID'  without having the `_` and then with `paste` (`paste0` have `sep=""` while `paste` have `sep = ' "`) that is the difference.  You can check the documentation of `?paste0`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `gsub()` and regular expressions. If there are three or more consecutive digits at the end it will add a `"_1`".

```
df1 <- gsub(".*?(\\d{3,})$", "\\1_1", df1$ID)
df1
# [1] "130239_1" "130241_1" "130244_1" "130250_2" "130313_2" "130248_2" "130308_3"
```

***Data***

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("130239", 
"130241", "130244", "130248_2", "130250_2", "130308_3", "130313_2"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner using anonymous function, `Filter` and `grepl`.

```r
 df1[df1$ID %in% (Filter(function(x) !grepl("\\_", x), df1$ID)),] <- paste(df1[df1$ID %in% (Filter(function(x) !grepl("\\_", x), df1$ID)),], "_1", sep ="")

#         ID
# 1 130239_1
# 2 130241_1
# 3 130244_1
# 4 130250_2
# 5 130313_2
# 6 130248_2
# 7 130308_3
```

This too can produce a similar result.

```r
df1[df1$ID %in% df1[!grepl("\\_", df1$ID), ],] <- paste(df1[df1$ID %in% df1[!grepl("\\_", df1$ID), ],], "_1", sep ="")

#         ID
# 1 130239_1
# 2 130241_1
# 3 130244_1
# 4 130250_2
# 5 130313_2
# 6 130248_2
# 7 130308_3
```

## Data

```r
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("130239", "130241", "130244", "130250_2", 
 "130313_2", "130248_2", "130308_3")), class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```